# Passing function output isn't correct in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays

This program will ask user for numbers, and then will sort them, and display how many triplets are in the array. If i enter {1,2,3,3,3,4,5,3,3,6,7}, it will be 3 triplets.

I don't know what happens in my `void triplet(int count, int uin[])` function; it is not working. Please help me to fix this.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void sorting(int count, int uin[]);
void triplet(int count, int uin[]);

int uin[30];
int i;
int done;
int count = 0;

int main()
{
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        printf("plase input the number: ");
        done = scanf_s("%d", &uin[i]);

        if (done != EOF)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    sorting(count, uin);
    triplet(count, uin);
    return 0;
}    

void sorting(int count, int uin[])
{
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < count - 1; j++)
        {
            if (uin[i]<uin[j])
            {
                temp = uin[i];
                uin[i] = uin[j];
                uin[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}    

void triplet(int count, int uin[])
{
    int i;
    int counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (uin[i] == uin[i + 1] && uin[i + 2])
        {
            counter++;
        }
        printf("\n%d\n", counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: When the loop is in its last iteration (when `i` equals `count - 1`), what do you think `uin[i + 1]` and `uin[i + 2]` will get their numbers from?

Comment: Two bugs. Too many iterations in loop, and missing left hand side in second test.

Comment: got all things fixed, now is working perfect, thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uin[i] == uin[i + 1] && uin[i + 2]` should be `uin[i] == uin[i + 1] && uin[i] == uin[i + 2]`. Study these two carefully and make sure you understand the difference!

Also, as Joachim pointed out, the loop condition should be `i < count - 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when arrays are used as parameters of functions then the first parameter is the array itself and the second parameter is the number of elements in the array. So instead of

```
void triplet(int count, int uin[]);
```

I would declare the function the following way

```
void triplet( const int uin[], int n );
```

Your function definition is invalid. First of all it uses invalid condition in if statement

```
if (uin[i] == uin[i + 1] && uin[i + 2])
```

and secondly there is an attempt to access memory beyond the array.

The function could be defined as

```
void triplet( const int uin[], int n )
{
    int i;
    int counter = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i + 2 < n; i++ )
    {
        counter += uin[i] == uin[i + 1] && uin[i + 1] == uin[i + 2];
    }

    printf( "\n%d\n", counter );
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion about argument order is the classic way to do it, but there's room to think that C99 changes that and `void triplet(int count, int uin[count]);` would make some sense (and then `count` must precede `uin` in the argument list).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I do not see any sense in the reverse order.